# findAndModify working on shell but not in my app

Tags: mongodb, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I have readWrite role which supposed to give me the ability to use `findAndModify()`, which works when I connect to my mongo (4.2) machine, but from my app (play framework scala app using reactive mongo ver 0.18.8) I get the following error message:

> "exception":"play.api.libs.json.JsResultException:
>   JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(CommandError[code=13,
>   errmsg=not authorized on myServiceName to execute command {
>   findAndModify: \"events\", query: { status: \"READY\", retries: { $lt:
>   5 }, lockedUntil: { $lt: new Date(1574066602281) } },
>   bypassDocumentValidation: true, writeConcern: { w: 1, j: false },
>   upsert: false, update: { $set: { lockedUntil: new Date(1574066722281)
>   }, $inc: { retries: 1 } }, new: true, $db: \"myServiceName\" }

Comment: Does `find()` work from your play app?

Comment: yes, find and insert works

Comment: Check the credentials/authdb configured: `not authorized on myServiceName to execute command`